# Can not develop the second Azure function directly in the portal(only the first function is allowed to be developed in portal)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using Azure(Free subscription) with function version 3.x (.Net Core 3.1).
the problem is that it is not possible to develop the second function using the "Develop in portal" option after the first one was published using VS2019 publish wizard.
How to add the second function to the function app using the "Develop in portal" editor?

[image: Azure portal function editor image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create am Azure function in VS2019 and publish it to the portal
2. Go to the portal, select the new function app and try to add the second function using "Develop in portal" option

Result: "Develop in portal" option is not available

Note: if the first function is created using the "Develop in portal" option, then the second one also can be created in portal using the same procedure.

Comment: @Peter That's correct.  You should answer it

Comment: @CSharpRocks you're right, done

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, once deployed using VS 2019 you need to add new functions to the same function app using the code that is being deployed. So you need to add multiple functions to the solution.

There should also be a message warning you about the function app being in a readonly state due to this. For example:

[image]

Comment: If the function is published using the VS2019 wizard with unchecked flag "Run from package file(recommended)" then it is possible to add more functions from the azure portal. In this case, the message "Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file.." is no more visible.

Comment: Yes, but you will loose the [benefits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#benefits-of-running-from-a-package-file) and are no longer following the recommendations.

Comment: @Igor do mind that after redeployment using visual studio your portal based functions will be removed!

Comment: Yes, the deployment will overwrite everything, this fact is not obvious and will lead to the loss of old code or binaries.[https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/18258]